# Crop image and stretch crop to 100% using CSS

Tags: html, css, crop

I have an image width 2200px.
I need to cut 10% left and right.

The remaining 80% need to fill 100% of page width, how to?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add 2 wraps around `<img>`.
2. Extend inner wrap with negative margin on both sides.
3. Add `overflow: hidden` on outer wrap to hide extended part.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="image-frame">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2200x1000">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-container .image-frame {
  margin: 0 -10%;
}
.image-container img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-container .image-frame {
  margin: 0 -10%;
}
.image-container img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="image-frame">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2200x1000">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[img with 10% off and the black is what has to be showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GSBr.png)

Look the image above, is this what you mean? 
The black part is the part you want to have showed right.

Then you can probably go to photoshop or even pain and cut 10% of both sides off.